# What does 'd' mean in 'syslogd'?

Tags: syslog

I see many articles mention `syslogd`, but when I search the web I only get information about `syslog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see a 'd' at the end of a program that seems out of place, it means that it's a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).

Comment: "Whenever" is too much. See `sed`, `dd`, `useradd`, `id`,…

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski well whenever there is a d that seems out of place.